Подключение к базе успешное, но активного пользователя нет
Только изучаю программирование на Go. Написал код для подключения к базе данных(PostgreSQL) для пользователя test. При отправке запроса на подключение проверка подключения проходит. После этого я смотрю список активных пользователей в базе, но там висит только postgres. Если после подключения сделать GET запросы, то они крашат сервер, сыпится гора ошибок и консоль зависает.
type User struct {
    User     string `json:"user"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    DBName   string `json:"dbname"`
}

var db *sql.DB

func connectHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        http.Error(w, "Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
    // Чтение данных из запроса
    var conectionInfo User
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&conectionInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("JSON decode error: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "Invalid input", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    //Строка подключения
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", conectionInfo.User, conectionInfo.Password, conectionInfo.DBName)
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to connect to database: %v", err)
        return
    }

    // Проверка подключения
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to ping database: %v", err)
        return
    }
    // Отправка ответа клиенту
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("Successfully connected to the database!"))
}

func main() {
    // Настройка маршрутов
    http.HandleFunc("/connect", connectHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/tasks", handlers.GetAllTasksHandler(db))
    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/task", handlers.GetIdTaskHandler(db))
    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/task/create", handlers.CreateTaskHandler(db))
    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/task/update", handlers.UpdateTaskHandler(db))
    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/task/delete", handlers.DeleteTaskHandler(db))

    // Запуск сервера
    log.Println("Server is running on port 8081...")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start server: %v", err)
    }
}

Ошибки:
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1898 +0xbe
panic({0x598b80?, 0x844c10?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:770 +0x132
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0x6721a0, 0x8dc6c0}, 0x1)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1310 +0x54
database/sql.(*DB).query(0x0, {0x6721a0, 0x8dc6c0}, {0x5ebedb, 0x13}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0xe0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1749 +0x57
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext.func1(0xe9?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1732 +0x4f
database/sql.(*DB).retry(0x7?, 0xc00002d850)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1566 +0x42
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0x3135ea?, {0x6721a0?, 0x8dc6c0?}, {0x5ebedb?, 0x5967e0?}, {0x0?, 0xc0000ca124?, 0xd?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1731 +0xc5
database/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1745
github.com/apelsinkoo09/task-manager/internal/models.ReadAll(0x0?)
        C:/Users/Maksim/YandexDisk/Task-manager/internal/models/task.go:24 +0x6d
main.main.GetAllTasksHandler.func1({0x671bc0, 0xc0000bc0e0}, 0xc00002db30?)
        C:/Users/Maksim/YandexDisk/Task-manager/internal/handlers/taskHandler.go:18 +0x28
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x8572d0?, {0x671bc0?, 0xc0000bc0e0?}, 0x51e17a?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2166 +0x29
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x3256f9?, {0x671bc0, 0xc0000bc0e0}, 0xc0000a2240)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2683 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc000090120?}, {0x671bc0?, 0xc0000bc0e0?}, 0x6?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:3137 +0x8e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0000aa000, {0x6722b8, 0xc000022f30})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2039 +0x5e8
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve in goroutine 1
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:3285 +0x4b4
exit status 0xc000013a

Обработчик:
func GetAllTasksHandler(db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc { //db - соединение с базой
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // хендлер
        //  w http.ResponseWriter - интерфейс для записи ответа клиенту
        //  r *http.Request - структура принимаемого запроса от клиента
        tasks, err := models.ReadAll(db)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Unable to retrieve tasks", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            // Сообщение клиенту об ошибке
            // http.StatusInternalServerError - 500 статус
            return
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json") // установка заголовка http ответа в формате ключ, значения, запись в карту. Формат отправляемых значений json
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(tasks)                   // кодирование в формат json
    }
}

Выражение:
type Task struct {
    Id          int64     `json:"id"`
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
    Status      string    `json:"status"`
    Priority    int       `json:"priority"`
    Created_at  time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    Updated_at  time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    User_id     int       `json:"user_id"`
}

func ReadAll(db *sql.DB) ([]Task, error) {
    result, err := db.Query("select * from tasks") //Query возвращает итерратор, надо пройти по всем!!! строчкам
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer result.Close()

    var tasks []Task

    for result.Next() { // next() подготавливает следующую строку для чтения с помощью метода scan()

        var task Task

        err := result.Scan( // проверка на ошибки в конкретной строке. Scan сканирует строки и назначает им переменные соответствующего типа
            &task.Id,
            &task.Title,
            &task.Description,
            &task.Status,
            &task.Priority,
            &task.Created_at,
            &task.Updated_at,
            &task.User_id,
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("failed to scan row: %v", err)
        }
        tasks = append(tasks, task)
        log.Printf("Task: %+v\n", task)
    }
    err = result.Err() // поиск общих ошибок
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    return tasks, nil
}


Так а где код обработки собственно запросов? И где ваша "гора ошибок"? Всё это должно быть прямо в вопросе.

Дополнил вопрос

Я Golang вообще не знаю, но разве вот здесь не происходит сразу вызов метода GetAllTasksHandler:  http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/tasks", handlers.GetAllTasksHandler(db))? При том, что db ещё не инициализирован в этот момент. Не нужна ли там какая-то лямбда в качестве хэндлера, или может db вообще не надо туда передавать, а брать глобально эту переменную, так же как в connectHandler?

Вы когда функцию со скобками указываете, вы её сразу вызываете. А вам тут нужно ссылку на функцию передать, чтобы она вызывалась когда нужно будет обработать HTTP запрос. Как это у вас для connectHandler сделано. Хотя возможно я что-то не знаю про Golang и тут это именно так и делается?

connectHandler устанавливает соединение с базой изменя переменную db, которая является указателем. Остальные обработчики уже с этой переменной работают. HandleFunc вызывает функцию-обработчик если поступил соответсвующий запрос. Соответственно в функцию передается подключение к бд, коим и является переменная db. А эта функция уже вызывает метод для обращения к базе данных

Ещё раз. Вот тут вы передали в HandleFunc ссылку на функцию http.HandleFunc("/connect", connectHandler), а вот тут вы вызвали функцию с параметром db и передали в HandleFunc результат её работы: http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/tasks", handlers.GetAllTasksHandler(db)). Попытайтесь понять разницу. Что вы передали во втором случае в HandleFunc - я вообще не очень понимаю. А нужно передать ссылку на функцию, по которой её можно вызвать. Кроме того, у этой функции ещё и сигнатура (параметры) должны быть определённые.

HandleFunc имеет вот такую структуру func http.HandleFunc(pattern string, handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request))
Второй параметр это то, что является результатом вызова функции GetAllTasksHandler. Посмотрите что возвращает обработчик. Передаю я соединение с базой данных

А, всё, я не прав. Спасибо за разъяснения, теперь всё увидел. Просто в вопросах по Питону это частая ошибка была, я и подумал, что тут тоже самое. Видимо, дело в чём-то другом. Извините за неправильную версию.

@CrazyElf да ничего страшного)

Какая именно ошибка (error) у ваз возникает? Вы их логируете через log.Println, а надо возвращать и смотреть. Добавьте содержимое такой ошибки в пост.

Решение оказалось до безобразия простое. Необходимо для каждого маршрутизатора сделать проверку на существование подключения к базе и внутри тела функции вызывать хандлер:
http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/tasks", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if db == nil {
            http.Error(w, "Database not connected", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        GetAllTasksHandler(db)(w, r)
    })

